# can't login with facebook on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, parse-platform

I am trying to login to a facebook account without the admin and test user I have been testing with.  This is using the Parse.com framework facebook login utility.  I get the error:

```
NSLocalizedDescription=User is not a test user owned by the application
```

My code to authenticate with facebook is hitting this condition:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:nil block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"User doesn't exist");
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                message:error.localizedDescription
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
```

I have set my app to: "Live and Available to All Users" in the facebook developer app dashboard.

Why am I receiving this error and how do I allow my app to be logged in by any user with a facebook account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was already logged in in the simulator with a non valid account.